# Browser crash when calling for a function with a for-loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to show what the correct answer for a question will be if the wrong one are selected.
I have stored 5 questions in a JSON-object list and I store what the user choose in an array.

The function I use to append what has been answered is:

```
    function userAnswers(){
        $("#result").append('<div id="yourAnswers"></div>');
        //rememberAnswer is the name of the array that have stored the data during the quiz
        for(i = 0; i < rememberAnswer .length; i++){
            $("#yourAnswers").append('<p>'+rememberAnswer [i][0]+'</p>');
            if(rememberAnswer [i][2] == 1){
                $("#yourAnswers").append('<p style="color: green;">'+rememberAnswer [i][1]+'</p><br/>');
            } else {
                $("#yourAnswers").append('<p style="color: red;">'+rememberAnswer [i][1]+'</p><br/>');
                //$("#yourAnswers").append('<p style="color: green;">The correct answer is: '+ correct([i])+'</p>');
// This makes the browser crash when
            }
        }
    }
```

The function for correct()

```
function correct(id){
    var test = quiz.question[id].answers; //Getting the answers from JSON-list
    var text;
    for(i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
        if(test [i].correct_answer == 1){
            text = test[i].answer;
            break;
        }
    }
    return text;    
}
```

The funny thing is that if I only have one question in the json list it all works. But when I try to execute it with all five, the browser crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not declaring your loop variables ("i"):

```
for(var i = 0; i < test.length; i++){ // <-- add the "var" keyword
```

Because of that, the variable "i" is global, so the "correct" function stomps on the value of the variable. Both functions should declare "i" with `var`.

Comment: Wow, thnaks! It's working perfect now. I will keep that in mind for later